MacOS Intune Platform SSO not prompting to register device until Company Portal is opened
I'm deploying Platform SSO to allow our Mac users to sign into their devices without the need for a "build process", similar to autopilot on Windows.
I've followed this guide and it all works, except that the user has to open and sign in to Company Portal before they are prompted to register the device via the notification pop up in step 5 of the guide.
Has anyone else experienced this, and where should I be looking for troubleshooting information?
